# programming logic of GPIO register of efr32

Tags: embedded

I have the following line from the function shown below.

```
  GPIO->P[port].CTRL = (GPIO->P[port].CTRL
                        & ~(_GPIO_P_CTRL_SLEWRATE_MASK
                            | _GPIO_P_CTRL_SLEWRATEALT_MASK))
                       | (slewrate << _GPIO_P_CTRL_SLEWRATE_SHIFT)
                       | (slewrateAlt << _GPIO_P_CTRL_SLEWRATEALT_SHIFT);
```

`GPIO->P[port].CTRL` is particularly complex structure I am having problem to understand.

I understand `[]` is an array,
`->` is a register,
`.` is object oriented property.

How do I connect all of them and see the logic in this line?

The code in context:

```
__STATIC_INLINE void GPIO_SlewrateSet(GPIO_Port_TypeDef port,
                                      uint32_t slewrate,
                                      uint32_t slewrateAlt)
{
  EFM_ASSERT(GPIO_PORT_VALID(port));
  EFM_ASSERT(slewrate <= (_GPIO_P_CTRL_SLEWRATE_MASK
                          >> _GPIO_P_CTRL_SLEWRATE_SHIFT));
  EFM_ASSERT(slewrateAlt <= (_GPIO_P_CTRL_SLEWRATEALT_MASK
                             >> _GPIO_P_CTRL_SLEWRATEALT_SHIFT));

  GPIO->P[port].CTRL = (GPIO->P[port].CTRL
                        & ~(_GPIO_P_CTRL_SLEWRATE_MASK
                            | _GPIO_P_CTRL_SLEWRATEALT_MASK))
                       | (slewrate << _GPIO_P_CTRL_SLEWRATE_SHIFT)
                       | (slewrateAlt << _GPIO_P_CTRL_SLEWRATEALT_SHIFT);
}
```

Comment: The structure is specific to the MCU you are using and you have not specified.  You will get a better answer if you did that.  Also you have not really asked a coherent question.  What does "_How do i connect all of them and see the logic in this line?_" actually mean.  Are you asking for an explanation of the code?  Did you literally mean the "_logic_" in the sense of the bit-wise Boolean operations or are you using the work "logic" in a less technical sense.  I thing the terms "logic" and "connect" are misused in this context perhaps?

Comment: In fact it looks like "_structure_" is misused here too.  Do you simply mean "_syntax_"?  Structure has specific  meaning in C code, and `GPIO->P[port].CTRL` is _not_ a structure, it is a register.  It is never a good idea in a question to try to answer it your self or state your "understanding" because you are probably wrong.  `->` is a structure member access operator when the left operand is a pointer-to-a-structure-object, `.` is a structure member access operator when the left operand is a structure-object.

Answer (score 0):

GPIO is the base pointer to the GPIO subsystem structure. This structure contains an array of ports. Each port has registers associated with it. These are represented as a member of the port structure. In the code you posted, the CTRL register is being modified.

https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efr32bg1/html/group__EFR32BG1P333F256GM48__Peripheral__Declaration.html#ga1037b18e2d226fe7d327d4a6f17a21c1

Comment: Hello Benny,I have tried to debug the code and see the inner dynamics of the GPIO base pointer As shown in picture 2 bellow , the debugger says that the value of port is gpioPortA[0].Then i went to the subsystem structure  shown in picture 3.
our value is cell 0 in gpioPortA structure.but in the code its gpio->P[port].CTRL
so we go to cell gpioPortA[0] inside P array so we get P[gpioPortA[0]] cell .
how can i know the exact value of gpioPortA[0] so i will see it in the struct of photo 3?

https://usaupload.com/6UlG/3.jpg
https://usaupload.com/6UlH/1.jpg
https://usaupload.com/6UlI/2.jpg

Comment: @lub2354 don't use comments to ask new questions.  Post a new question.  Comments are not suited for this and you are addressing just one person rather than the entire community.